# How can I make a backup of my Microsoft Office CD 2007 CD?

Tags: backup, microsoft-office, burning

I have a legal CD of Microsoft Office 2007, and I am trying to make a backup copy CD of this.

On Mac, with [Disco](http://discoapp.com/), the burner says the CD is encrypted.

In Linux, with brasero, it reads the disk for many minutes but doesn't complete the copy of information.

How can I make a backup of my Microsoft Office CD 2007 CD?

Comment: I promise you the contents on the cd ia not encrypted. What version of Microsoft Office are you dealing with?  Once you provide more information within the question itself I will take my vote down back.

Comment: is a MS office 2007

Comment: On a Windows machine copy the contents of the media to a folder on your desktop.  Once it finishes copying just burn the contents of the folder to a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

To save a step of creating an ISO backup, the ISO for most Office versions are available from the microsoft site.
Here's one that seems to allow a download if you have your office product key:

[Microsoft Office 2007 download](http://www.microsoft.com/office/downloads/)

Comment: The link only lets you download those versions ( it will check your authentication key ) and prevent the download.  I was trying to get a copy of Office 2007 to my mother a few weeks ago, I have the authentication code and the original media, she is in another state.  It prevented me from being able to download it.

Comment: Weird. It certainly looks like it promises to give you Office 2007 if you have an Office 2007 product key for one of those there versions. We use a different version, so I couldn't get further either.

Comment: What you discovered is exactly my point.  There are additional versions `Enterprise` is often sold at a discount to students and teachers.